# Executing bash commands in Ruby with variable interpolation?

Tags: ruby, bash

I have the following bash command in my script:

```
exec 'fsc request #{board}'
```

where board is a variable in my code. But the variable is not being passed to the command line but

```
#{board}
```

is being passed literally.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: This is outside the scope of this question, but please DO NOT pass user input to another program like that. If the `board` variable was inputted by a user (and you are making an application that more people than just you will use), a malicious user could set `board` to `misc-data && echo test` and arbitrarily run code on your computer. Edit: Not saying you are doing this, just advising against it in case you are or decide to in the future

Comment: Thank you. I was just rapid proto typiong. I will add in additional security when i go for final implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use double quotes `"` instead of single ones. Single quotes will not interpolate variables.

```
foo = 'bar'

puts '#{foo}'
#{foo}

puts "#{foo}"
bar
```